# Condition on 4 numbers

Tags: javascript

I have two variables which must display an integer.

The two variables must be in 2 ranges `30...40` and `60...80`

For example:

If the first number displays `35` and the second number `65`. The condition is `true`.

Another example:

If the first number displays `35` and the second `110`, the condition is `false`.

My problem is that for the first number, I initialize the value to `35` and the second to `65` and I obtain a `false` instead of `true`.

```
let nb1 = 35;
let nb2 = 65;

if( (nb1 >= 30 && nb1 <= 40 && nb1 >= 60 && nb1 <= 80)  && (nb2 >= 30     
    && nb2 <= 40 && nb2 >= 60 && nb2 <= 80)  ){
  console.log(true);
 } else {
  console.log(false);
}
```

What is wrong with my condition?

Thank you

Comment: `nb1 >= 30 && nb1 <= 40 && nb1 >= 60 && nb1 <= 80` can never be true. There is no number that is `<= 40` **AND** `>= 60` at the same time.

Comment: You might also consider some helper functions to avoid the repeated and hard to read numbers  `const inFirstRange = (n) => n >= 30 && n <= 40;  const inSecondRange = (n) => n >= 60 && n <= 80; const inRange = (n) => inFirstRange(n) || inSecondRange(n); if(inRange(nb1) && inRange(nb2)){ ...` This looks better on multiple lines, but only really belongs in a comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number can't be in both ranges simultaneously, you need to use an `or` condition:

```js
 let nb1 = 35;
 let nb2 = 65;

 if(((nb1 >= 30 && nb1 <= 40) || (nb1 >= 60 && nb1 <= 80)) && ((nb2 >= 30     
        && nb2 <= 40) || (nb2 >= 60 && nb2 <= 80))){
     //condition(s) are met
     console.log(true);
 } else {
     console.log(false);
 }
```